# Python 3.3.2: Error on html module import

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a clean install of Python 3.3.2 on Windows 7. I'm trying to import *html.parser.HTMLParser*, using the example from the documentation: [Simple HTML and XHTML parser](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

But I'm getting the error:

```
>>> from html.parser import HTMLParser
aee4
gg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "htmlang.py", line 1, in <module>
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
  File "c:\Python33\lib\html\parser.py", line 13, in <module>
    import warnings
  File "c:\Python33\lib\warnings.py", line 6, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "c:\Python33\lib\linecache.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "c:\Python33\lib\tokenize.py", line 37, in <module>
    __all__ = token.__all__ + ["COMMENT", "tokenize", "detect_encoding",
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'
```

I have just opened the interpreter and typed the import line. Why it isn't working as expected? Why it is printing the weird "aee4" and "gg2" strings?

Comment: Do you have a file called `token.py` in your current directory? Something is shadowing an installed module.

Comment: Yes! It was a token.py file in the same folder. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just write "import HTMLParser" and it will work

Comment: Your solution doesn't actually match the symptoms.